# Run random command in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, random

I would like to randomly select one random command in a bash script.

I have tried commands like

`echo $(( $RANDOM % 12 ))`

But they work in the UNIX command line but not in my bash script.

Anyone have a solution for my problem?

Comment: Do you use `sh` to execute your script instead of `bash`?

Comment: Yes. This is the error code I get if I run my script arithmetic expression: expecting primary: "  % 12 "

Comment: Execute using script using `bash`, not using `sh`.

Comment: chmod +x to your script too

Comment: Just so you know, the `$` within the `$((...))` isn't required. You can do `echo $((RANDOM % 12))`.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/81568/50855

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-- Updated answer as per discussion in comments --

**For Bash Users:**

> Code given in question works fine. Just don't forget to set permissions to +x (grants executable permission to all). Eg: `chmod +x myscript.sh`
>
> **Caution:** Don't set RANDOM to a value. It looses its special properties.
>
> **Bash man page** says-
>
> > RANDOM Each time this parameter is referenced, a random integer
> >     between 0 and 32767 is generated. The sequence of random numbers may
> >     be initialized by assigning a value to RANDOM. If RANDOM is unset, it
> >     loses its special properties, even if it is sub- sequently reset.

**For dash Users:**

> sh in ubuntu is a symbolic link to dash.
>   **dash** does not support RANDOM variable, it is just another variable.
>
> If you are bound to use sh, you can use date function to generate
>   pseudo randoms only if your script is not time-dependent. (if your
>   script runs at strict intervals of time, it might produce same values)
>
> ```
> RANDOM=`date '+%s'`
> echo $(( $RANDOM % 12 )) # To generate random numbers less than 12
> ```

**In General:**

If you want to generate true random numbers use this-

```
dd if=/dev/urandom count=1 2> /dev/null | cksum | cut -f1 -d" "
```

Source: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/shell-script-random-variable-4088/

Comment: I think the downvote was because his problem was not how to generate a real random, nevertheless good info I didn't know the effect of `RANDOM=a; echo $RANDOM` so +1 (I didn't downvote you BTW)

Comment: I don't think you need to seed anything to be able to use `$RANDOM`.

Comment: @Jonathan Try to run `echo $(( $RANDOM % 12 ))` using sh, without seeding RANDOM, you will get an error `arithmetic expression: expecting primary: "  % 12 "`

Comment: Curious…using `bash` on Mac OS X 10.9.3 Mavericks, I can use either `bash -c 'echo $RANDOM'` or `sh -c 'echo $RANDOM'` and get a random number without any ado.  This is Apple's version based on 3.2.51.  This should be equivalent to your command.  (_Indeed: `sh -c 'echo $(($RANDOM % 12))'` works fine._)  I don't know what the difference is, but I've never encountered a shell with support for RANDOM that required a seed…but then I hadn't encountered `dash`!  On Ubuntu 14.04 with `/bin/sh` a symlink to `dash`, then I get into trouble.  Just one more reason not to like `dash` very much.

Comment: Actually, `dash` doesn't support `$RANDOM` as a special variable; you can set it just like any other variable, and echo it as often as you like, and you get the same value each time — unlike `$RANDOM` in `bash` or `ksh`.

Comment: My bad, I'll update my answer. It would be great if you can edit it :)

Comment: It does work the other way around.  You can remove the special behaviour of variables like `$RANDOM` with `unset`. There exists no way to restore the special behaviour after that. (Verified in [tag:bash] and [tag:ksh]93)

Comment: For true random, `/dev/urandom` is cool, but you don't need `dd`+`cksum`+`cut`… `od` is enough, e.g., `od -An -tu -N2 /dev/urandom`. (the `-N2` option tells how many bytes to read, here 2 bytes–you can replace with `1`, `3` or `4` with no further adaptations).

Answer (score 1):

Create the shell script test.sh

```
chmod +x test.sh
```

content of test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(( $RANDOM % 12 ))
```

Run it via

```
bash test.sh
```

or

```
./test.sh
```