# Run random process in ubuntu terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to know if there is a way to run random processes to simulate normal activity from a user that could work in the PC.

For example generate random processes that consume resources as a browser or a pdf would, until has 50% or 60% of memory working.

I am trying to get data from virtual machines but I would like to have the most heterogeneous data that I could.

I have tried the following:

1. [Run random command in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465591/run-random-command-in-bash-script)
2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174688/how-can-i-start-a-process-with-any-name-which-does-nothing

But that's no exactly what I am looking for.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you run a web browser or PDF (viewer, I assume) directly, instead of trying to simulate them?

Comment: Because if I do that, I would obtain a dataset from machine resources only with those two processes and I will have a homogeneous dataset and what I want is data that simulates a person who was working normally. All this has to be automated and cannot be done manually.

Comment: I am not really following you. Most web browsers (and other major softwares) do support a command-line interface which is very similar to what a user would do (except for the clicking around) and you can run as many as you like. I do not see a problem there neither in the automation, nor in the number of running processes.

Comment: are you fluent in Python? (i.e. if I write a couple of lines in Python would that be helpful?)

Comment: Yes, of course, the automatization is in Python. Forget the browsers by the moment. Suppose that I just want to run 10 process in one virtual machine (with Ubuntu) and other with 40 process, etc. I don't want all that processes are browsers, that's why I am asking for "random process".

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you?

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import random
import subprocess
import time
import psutil


timeout = 5 * 60  # seconds
poll_time = 5  # seconds
mem_limit = psutil.virtual_memory().total * (50/100)  # limit mem usage at 50%
cmds = [
   'firefox www.some_website.com',
   'firefox www.other_website.com',
   'okular some_document.pdf',
   'vlc some_video.mp4',
   'vlc some_audio.mp3',
   # etc.
]

procs = []
quit = False
init_time = time.time()
while not quit:
    if mem_limit < psutil.virtual_memory().used:
        i = random.randint(0, len(cmds))
        cmd = cmds[i]
        procs.append(subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True))
    time.sleep(poll_time)
    if timeout > (time.time() - init_time):
        for proc in procs:
            proc.kill()
        quit = True
```